# 2/4 Bit Shift Register

Tags: shift-register

I'm looking for a 2 or 4 bit shift register that I can shift data into, and on the 5th shift into the device it will shift the previous data back out on the Dout.

I am looking for a shift register that acts a lot like the MAX6969 from Maxim, yet is smaller than that.

Comment: Would any of the chips mentioned in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6676/which-sipo-chip-is-better-74hc4094-or-74hc595-or-something-else work for you?

Answer (score 8):

have you tried looking in the 74xx series of logic? Pick your favorite flavor. 74HC194 and 74HC195 are 4-bit shift registers; 74HC174 (quad flip-flop) and 74HC175 (hex flip-flop) can be made into shift registers.

edit: based on your comments, why don't you use an HC594 (output) or HC597 (input)? They're 8-bit registers, easily cascadable to arbitrary lengths, compatible with a SPI interface as well as plain old clocking.

Comment: I'm looking for something that allows me put several together in a daisy chain, much like the MAX6969 from Maxim whereby when I click on on Cin, 16 clock cycles later it shows up at Dout. So to have two of the same chips next to each other I can send out 32 bits of data, and both chips will now contain data.