# Playing with a shift register and some LEDs

Tags: led, shift-register

Building on [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11344/building-a-simple-mcu-driven-array-of-leds) question, I've now got a [shift register](http://3ln.org/Media/Default/Datasheets/DM74LS164.pdf) to play with, and I've been trying to work it manually with a couple of switches, like so:
[image: shift register LED array]

I have resistors (2.2K) between the switches and VCC, even though that's not shown in the schematic. It doesn't work, though.

When I press the clock switch, sometimes an LED will light, and sometimes it won't. Sometimes several LEDs light. Never does it "shift" a zero "bit". If I just hit the input switch a bunch of times, it shifts in bits, sometimes one at a time, sometimes several at a time.

What gives? What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The switch is "bouncing":  Each time you open or close it, there is a period where it makes a bit of noise on the clock line.  The chip sees this noise as multiple transitions and clocks in more bits than you intended.  To fix this, you need a "debouncing" circuit.  Google should find you something.

edit:

You can't just switch voltage to an input like that.  Then the input is at +5V when the switch is closed, but floating when the switch is open.  You need at least a pulldown resistor after the switch.

Comment: By "pulldown resistor after the switch" I assume you mean that I need to connect the inputs to ground through a high-value resistor (5k or more)? Remember, it's been 20 years since my limited education on the subject...

Comment: http://www.seattlerobotics.org/encoder/mar97/basics.html was extremely helpful. I'll set it up like that.

Comment: Also, I can debounce the switch with something like a simple 100nF ceramic cap?

Comment: A 100nF will help, but a capacitor is not a great debouncer.  Would be better to follow it with a 74hc14 or similar.

Comment: Note you only need to debounce the clock line.  The other lines aren't edge-sensitive.

Comment: Look at the datasheet to see if a minimum clock rise/fall time is specified.  If so, the capacitor may slow you down too much.  Then the 74hc14 is essential.