# To BJT or not to BJT: That is the question

Tags: mosfet, bjt, npn, pnp, fet

Practically speaking, when is it better to use a BJT vs a FET **for swtiching** (not as a linear amp)?

Given that FETs have both N-channel and P-channel forms, and BJTs come in NPN or PNP, it seems that you could use either in most cases with only minor circuitry differences.

**Question:**

- When would you use one versus the other?
- Are there applications where one is absolutely necessary such that the other will not work?

Again, note this question pertains only about switching loads (including PWM), but not for use as an RF amplifier.

Comment: Depletion-mode FET isn't the FET equivalent to PNP, that would be p-channel FET.

Comment: @pipe, updated question, thanks!

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13079/when-is-a-mosfet-more-appropriate-as-a-switch-than-a-bjt

Comment: So far as I know, there are no NFETs or PFETs that were used in the horizontal flyback of CRT TVs. I never saw one, even when FETs were being used most everywhere else. And there are domains of switching use where one or the other is to be preferred. It turns on details (wasted power dissipation being one of them, since neither approach covers the entire range of situations as a panacea.) But I think your question is really too broad. I know I don't have a comprehensive view and that it would take serious time to acquire one and then write about it. But yes, there are cases for each.

Comment: It's an interesting thought, but being so broad it's not really answerable beyond "well it depends"

Comment: @Lars Hankeln OP asked about a "FET". The answer you linked to asked about a "MOSFET". A FET can be a JFET or a MSOFET. Therefore, I consider this to be a different question.